# Setting the setActiveSelection where there is zero

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a tremendous volume of sparse matrix data, where i want to programmatically set as active cell wherever there is (0) when I run the below snippet (function).

Which would ease me for manipulation of code labels

The data is purely random. The process has to begin from the current active cell and it has to loop again from beginning if end of the data is found.

I get unexpected results,

```
function getzero() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var Values = range.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < Values[i].length; j++) {
            if (Values[i][j] == 0) {
                sheet.setActiveSelection(sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: sparse matrix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take care of finding all the zeros. Also added a menu for you to run the command from the sheets directly. Just paste code in the script editor and reload the sheet.

```
// This function addes a menu Zero and submenu getzero to access your function directly from spreadsheet
function onOpen(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var menu = [{name:"Find Zero",functionName: "getzero"}]
  ss.addMenu("Zeroes", menu)

}



function getzero() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var Values = range.getValues();
    var selectedRange = sheet.getActiveRange()
    // find active cells row and column
    var startRow  = selectedRange.getRow() -1
    var startCol = selectedRange.getColumn()
    var notFoundZero = true

    //Use the active cells row and column to start the loop
    for (var i = startRow; i < Values.length; i++) {
      if (i == startRow){
        var j = startCol
        } 
      else {
        j =0
      }

        for (j ; j < Values[i].length; j++) {
            // Using "===" makes sure the type is also match else blank is considered as zero too.
            if (Values[i][j] === 0) {
                Logger.log("Values Row X Col:" + i + " X " + j)
                //The below line works as well as sheet.setActiveSelection
                sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).activate()
                //Below code escapes the outer loop
                i = Values.length;
                // this boolean is used to runs or stops the next loop
                notFoundZero = false;
                // breaks inner loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }

  if(notFoundZero){
    for (var i = 0; i <= startRow; i++) {
      if (i == startRow){
        var runTill = startCol
      } 
      else {
         runTill = Values[i].length
      }

        for (var j=0 ; j < runTill; j++) {
            if (Values[i][j] === 0) {

                sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).activate()
                // same as above
                i = Values.length;
                //Used to alert if no more zeros found
                notFoundZero = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
   }

   if(notFoundZero)
   {
     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     ui.alert("No More zero Found")

   }


}
```

This will check cell values after selection if no zeroes are found it will check above the selection. But after that it will stop at the selection and alert no zeroes found, this prevents a runaway loop.

Give it a go and let me know how it goes.

**Edit:** Below Code for searching in reverse

**Below Code Has not been Tested, Might have errors. This was not the primary Question, hence did not check for errors.**

```
function getzeroRev() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var Values = range.getValues();
    var selectedRange = sheet.getActiveRange()
    // find active cells row and column
    var startRow  = selectedRange.getRow() -1
    var startCol = selectedRange.getColumn()
    var notFoundZero = true

    //Use the active cells row and column to start the loop

    for (var i = startRow; i >=0; i--) {
      if (i == startRow){
        var j = startCol
        } 
      else {
        j =values[i].length
      }

        for (j ; j >=0; j--) {
            // Using "===" makes sure the type is also match else blank is considered as zero too.
            if (Values[i][j] === 0) {
                Logger.log("Values Row X Col:" + i + " X " + j)
                //The below line works as well as sheet.setActiveSelection
                sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).activate()
                //Below code escapes the outer loop
                i = Values.length;
                // this boolean is used to runs or stops the next loop
                notFoundZero = false;
                // breaks inner loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }

  if(notFoundZero){
    for (var i = values.length; i >= startRow; i--) {
      if (i == startRow){
        var runTill = startCol
      } 
      else {
         runTill = 0
      }

        for (var j=0 ; j >= runTill; j--) {
            if (Values[i][j] === 0) {

                sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).activate()
                // same as above
                i = Values.length;
                //Used to alert if no more zeros found
                notFoundZero = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
   }

   if(notFoundZero)
   {
     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     ui.alert("No More zero Found")

   }


}
```

Comment: Thank you Jagan - this works awesome, any performance improvements will be appreciated, as I have a large volume (in many sheets) as I had described

Comment: What is your end goal here? What do you do after a cell with zero is activated?

Comment: The end goal is - I am given a sheet with certain values (co-ordinates) and the cell address, if 0 is found in the given cell address I must remove zero manually and insert the co-ordinates. The given co-ordinates are (hard copy). Can you tell me the change I need to be done for backward movement - sometime the cursor goes somewhere in awry. (you can just brief me up, i will try to do it myself)

Comment: Modify the for loop to go backward like so for(i = startRow; i >= 0; i--). This cause the row to got say 2>1>0. Similarly for going back in column  (i=startCol ;i >=0; i--). Also when you say hard copy, do you look at written/printed out sheet and enter the number manually? Brutal :/

Comment: The above code goes to an infinite loop, Even I couldn't do it, in-spite variable values were changed to "Values"

Comment: The getzerorev function?

Comment: Any solutions? in getzerorev